# How does a Component takes a function as its child?

Tags: reactjs

I saw code like this:

```
export const ProModeContext = React.createContext({ 
   proMode: false
})

export class ActionButton extends Component {
   
   render() {
      return (
         <ProModeContext.Consumer>
            {contextData =>
               <button
                  disabled={!contextData.proMode}
                  onClick={this.props.callback}>
                  {this.props.text}
               </button>
            }
         </ProModeContext.Consumer>
      )
   }
}
```

I alway think we can only pass component inside a component only as:

```
<ComponentA>
   <ComponentB />
</ComponentA>
```

and we can get ComponentA's children which is ComponentB

But how can we pass a function inside a rendered component/function as a child like:

```
<ComponentA>
   {() => console.log("Hello World")}
</ComponentA>
```

because when I try to get its children of ComponentA via `this.props.children`, it gets nothing, so the wrapped fucntion is not a child of ComponentA instance,  so how does `ProModeContext.Consumer` takes a function as its child and apply this function internally?

Comment: Like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-tyufcs?file=src%2FApp.tsx?

Comment: You have to wrap your function in `{}`

Answer (score 0):

You can define children as *render prop*, that is a function taking parameters from parents.

From the [Legacy React Docs](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html).

> The term “render prop” refers to a technique for sharing code between React components using a prop whose value is a function.
> A component with a render prop takes a function that returns a React element and calls it instead of implementing its own render logic.

```js
function ComponentA({children}) {
  const data = {}; // a state or data calculated by ComponentA
  return (
    <div>
      {children(data)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then you can use like this

```js
function Container() {
  return (
    <ComponentA>
      {(data) => <ComponentB data={data} />}
    </ComponentA>

  );
}
```

You can read more on this on [Using props other than `render`](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html#using-props-other-than-render) and in the new React Docs [Passing data with a render prop](https://react.dev/reference/react/cloneElement#passing-data-with-a-render-prop).